# Unmet dependencies, and 'apt-get -f install' not work (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

My friend gave me a vps and asked me to put a website on it. But I found it almost impossible to install any software:

For example:

```
root@ubuntu12:~# apt-get install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.17-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.13) but 2.17-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libnih1 : PreDepends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.17-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 nginx : Depends: nginx-full but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

```
root@ubuntu12:~# apt-get install htop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
htop is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.17-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.13) but 2.17-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 libnih1 : PreDepends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.17-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I think the problem is with `libc6` package, but I am afraid removing `libc6` would cause another problem. What is the proper solution I should take?

Comment: which ubuntu was there? it seems the system is heavily mis-used since the core package is incompatible (libc)

Comment: @Anwar Shah It is 12.04, I also think the system is in a mess now .

Comment: do you have ppa-purge installled? use that to remove all ppa

Comment: @Anwar Shah No, `The program 'ppa-purge' is currently not installed.`, `apt-get install ppa-purge` get same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable solution is Downloading and Installing `ppa-purge` manually and then remove the offending ppas. I highly suspects, this is caused by some PPAs.

1. Download and install `ppa-purge`. For 12.04, the official `ppa-purge` can be manually downloaded from this Ubuntu mirror http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/ppa-purge/ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr56_all.deb

   Download with wget

   ```
   wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/ppa-purge/ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr56_all.deb
   ```

   Install with `dpkg`

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr56_all.deb
   ```

   Assuming you downloaded the exact version
2. Then remove the PPAs one-by-one. You should have known what PPAs are added to the system.

   ```
   sudo ppa-purge ppa:repository-name/subdirectory
   ```

**Note 1**: This command will remove the ppa repository as well as the packages installed from that repository. So, simply removing the repository source line will not solve the problem.

**Note 2**: If you can't find the PPA name you can't look at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory and by looking at the `.list` files there, you'll get a hint of what PPAs are installed. Google can help with you to find the name of PPA from those file names.

Comment: It is `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`, I don't know the usage of  that ppa, but removing it does solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to know it helps. I recommend caution using PPA. that may cause a lot of headache